# Nested on() vs. delegated on()

Tags: jquery

What is the correct way to bind an event to an appended element?

I'm doing it like this (and it is working):

```
$('#element').on('click', function( event ) {
    $('#anything').append('<div class="delete"></div>');

    $('.delete').on('click', function( event ) {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Or should I use a delegated `on()` for the click on delete event outside of the first `on()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do like this with event delegation and i believe that you are gonna add the `.delete` element inside of `#element`,

```
$('#element').on('click', function( event ) {
    $('#anything').append('<div class="delete"></div>');
});

$('#anything').on('click', '.deleted' , function( event ) {
    $(this).closest("#element").remove();
});
```